# Accessing two matrices simultaneously in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, adjacency-matrix

I have two matrices, one of them is an adjacency matrix :
[image: *Red indicates the index associated]

another matrix is storing indices of above matrix like this :
[image: *Red indicates the index associated]

I want to apply some operations on say the 1st row of the matrix (i.e. `[1 5 7]`) simultaneously, how to access only 1st, 5th, and 7th row of original adjacency matrix in MATLAB?

Comment: Please provide an example input (as numbers, not an image!), an example operation, and the corresponding example output.

Comment: Posting your data as images makes it extremely inconvenient to actually use that data. Please replace these images with actual text we can copy and paste.

Comment: @beaker I didn't have any idea about writing matrices as code (this was my first question on StackOverflow). I will keep this in mind from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array as the row index into the adjacency matrix and you can either store that in a temporary variable or pass that directly to a function.

```
tmp = adjacency([1 5 7], :);
dothing(tmp)

% Or
dothing(adjacency([1 5 7], :));
```

Also you can assign back into those same rows using the array as an index again

```
adjacency([1 5 7], :) = dothing(adjacency([1 5 7], :));
```

Comment: Can I access a row of matrix using index ? For e.g. In Adjacency Matrix if I give input as 5, the output should be : "1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0". I know I can do this through Logical Indexing but I want to make use of  index specified by me(represented in Red box in the above image).

Comment: @ManishaKeim Yes, replace `[1 5 7]` with simply `5` above

Comment: Yaa.. I can do like this but what I want to do exactly is **from 2nd matrix if I pass 5 then it should select 5th row of 1st matrix** (its like pointers in C)

Comment: @ManishaKeim what do you mean "pass 5 to the second matrix"? Please show an example of what you're hoping to accomplish. The correspondence between the two matrices is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Say M is your matrix, you can access a specific element of  Matrix by doing :  `M(i,j)` where i and j are your line and column number.

You can acces a column by doing: `M(:,j)`where j is your column

You can access a line by doing: `M(i,:)`where i is your line